# Prove eigenvalue and find an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $5\times 5$ matrix, and suppose the sum of all rows is k, show that $\lambda = k$ is an eigenvalue and find a corresponding eigenvector.

To show that $\lambda = k$ is an eigenvalue we must show $\det(A - kI) = 0$ right?

Comment: "To show that $\lambda = k$ is an eigenvalue we must show $\det(A - kI) = 0$ right?" Well, that is the definition.  But it is not always the most straightforward way to show it.  Another way would be: find an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $k$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, so to do that, I find a vector such that $(A - kI)v = 0$ correct? So null space of $A - kI$?

Comment: Or, a vector $v$ such that $Av = kv$.  That amounts to the same thing and is sometimes more straightforward when you know something about $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Correct. In the matrix $A$, all rows sum to $k$. In the matrix $B = A - kI$, what is the sum in each row? What can you multiply a matrix by to sum its rows?

Comment: Is the sum of each row $k - 1$?

Comment: No. It used to be $k$, all entries changed, except the diagonal one. How does the diagonal entry in $B = A-kI$ differ from the diagonal entry of $A$?

Comment: It's $k$ less. So the sum of the rows, would be $k -k = 0$ then ?

Comment: @Marodian exactly. So what is $det(B)$?

Comment: I know it must be 0, but I am not sure why? Just because the sum of rows of $B$ is 0, why does that mean det(B) = 0?

Comment: @Marodian you are doing the same thing to all the rows -- summing them; this is equivalent to multiplying a vector of all 1's. So what is $B \cdot \vec{1}$? Then you see that $\vec{1}$ is a solution to $(A - kI)\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ so it must be an eigenvector. What is the corresponding eigenvalue, just read it off the equation?

Comment: $B \cdot \overrightarrow{1}$ would be equal to $\overrightarrow{0}$, so I see that the vector with all entries one, and the corresponding lambda would be $k$. Thanks!

Comment: @Marodian that $B\cdot \vec{x} = \vec{0}$ has non-all-zero solutions implies that the set of columns of $B$ is linearly dependent, hence it must have a zero determinant...

Comment: What theorem is that? Just because the null space has non zero solutions, how does that show the columns are LD?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the column vector whose entries are all $1$'s.